# Cannot cast SKNode to subclass of SKNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I am returning an `SKNode` from one function and I need to cast it to a custom `SKNode`. I get the error `Cannot assign value of`SKNode`to type`GroundNode. If I force cast, it compiles, but fails at runtime. What am I missing?

```
// Custom node class
class GroundNode: SKNode {
        weak var entity: GKEntity!
    }

// Return node function
func returnNode() -> SKNode {
    ...
    return node
}

// Where I am getting the error
func setupNode() {
    var ground: GroundNode
    ground = returnNode() // error here.
    //// ground = returnNode() as! GroundNode fails at runtime.
}
```

**EDIT**: I am getting an `SKNode` from an sks file. My `returnNode()` just get the child with name, and returns it to my `setupNode()` function. I need to add the entity property, so I want to cast my returned `SKNode` to a `GroundNode` type.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123264/subclassing-sknodes-created-with-spritekit-sks-scene-file?rq=1) stackoverflow post.

This works with `SKSpiteNode`, but apparently not with `SKNode`, which does not make much sense to me.

If I cast my `SKNode` from my sks file to a `GroundNode`, it crashes at runtime.

Comment: Might I ask why you are pursuing this setup? When assigning a regular SKNode to this GroundNode, you are promising whatever logic accessing this variable that it is a GroundNode - even though it might not be since returnNode can return _any_ SKNode object. Without more context, this sounds like a bad idea to me.

Comment: Are you sure that in `setupNode` the call to `returnNode` actually returns a `GroundNode` instance? It doesn't seems to be... Use the debugger to observe what really happens.

Comment: I think you've forgot to set your custom class, I've explain that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
// Custom node class
class GroundNode: SKNode {
    weak var entity: GKEntity! = GKEntity() // or some custom initialization...
}

// Where I am getting the error
func setupNode() {
   var ground: GroundNode
   ground = returnNode() as? GroundNode
}
```

This happened because returnNode output is a generic SKNode and you must explicit your casting to the subclassed GroundNode.

**EDIT**: 
Ok, with your update I think I've understand your issue, you've forgot to set the custom class for your GroundNode:

[image]

Comment: I need to add the Module name, but that fixed it. Crashes on other targets now because the module name does not match, but that is a separate issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## first

`returnNode()` returns an instance of `SKNode` class. It *might* also return an instance of derived class (e.g. `GroundNode`), but call site doesn't know that from the function declaration. You are trying to assign this instance to the variable of `SKNode`'s subclass - `GroundNode` which is **not appropriate in OOP**.

See [**Dynamic Binding**](http://users.dickinson.edu/~wahlst/356/ch12.pdf) OOP concept:

> In object- oriented programming languages, a variable of a superclass
>   type can contain a subclass instance.

(possibly, someone else could explain this in more details, but this is how things look to me)

## second

[Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html). When you suspect that some variable of a class type, might hold an instance of derived class, you could do a type casting in order to proof that.

`returnNode()` returns an instance of `SKNode` **OR** any derived class, but the call site wants to process only instances of derived class (`GroundNode`), hence one of type casting technique should be used.

```
import GameplayKit
import SpriteKit

// Custom node class
class GroundNode: SKNode {
    var entity: GKEntity = GKEntity()
}

// Return node function
func returnNode() -> SKNode {
    // let's assume that you are correctly getting an instance
    // of GroundNode class here, and return it from the function
    // as of SKNode type
    let returnNode: SKNode = GroundNode()
    return returnNode
}

func setupNode() {
    var groundNode: GroundNode?

    // Type Casting

    // Approach #1
    let someNode = returnNode()
    if someNode is GroundNode {
        groundNode = someNode as! GroundNode
    }

    // Approach #2
    groundNode = returnNode() as? GroundNode

    print("groundNode = \(groundNode)")
}
```

Comment: This took care of the crashing, but would make my node empty, as I was assigning it to an empty GroundNode.

Comment: Instance of what type `func returnNode()` should **actually** return at runtime (`GroundNode` or `SKNode`)? Are you trying to initialize `GroundNode` from `.sks`? Could you please shed some light on **what** you are actually trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I have updated my question. returnNode returns an SKNode. If I cast my SKNode to a GroundNode in `returnNode()` I get a crash at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

`func returnNode() -> GroundNode {`

Comment: I tried, but I am getting an SKNode from an SKS file. It can't cast SKNode to GroundNode. If I force cast, it crashes at runtime, not compile time.